# SelectionForeColor not working for link cells in DataGridViewLinkColumn of DataGridView

Tags: winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcellstyle, datagridviewlinkcolumn

In my Winform 4.5 app, I have a `DataGridView` with first column as a link column. I would like to have the link color of the selected link cell to be white. Since by default the background color of a selected row (or a cell) is blue and the `ForeColor` of all the links are also blue, when user selects a row (or a link cell) the text of the link is not readable. I tried writing the following code but it does not change the link color of selected link cell at all.

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewLinkCell cell in ((DataGridView)sender).SelectedCells)
    {
        if (cell.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            if (cell.Selected)
            {
                cell.Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle()
                {
                    SelectionForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then modified the above code as follows. But it changes the link color of all the links to white - that makes non-selected link cells to be not readable since the backcolor of those links is also white:

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewLinkCell cell in ((DataGridView)sender).SelectedCells)
        {
            if (cell.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                if (cell.Selected)
                {
                    cell.LinkColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tested both the codes by setting a breakpoint inside the foreach loop and selecting a link cell. I noticed that the code does go through exactly one iteration of the foreach loop correctly. Moreover, I have made no change to the default settings of the `DataGridViewLinkColumn`

**Edit**
By default the `DataGridView` looks like this on a row selection. Notice that the cell in the second column changes its `ForeColor` to white but not the cell in the first column:
[image]

---

I want it to looks like this on a row selection:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** The [CellLeave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellleave(v=vs.110).aspx) event will always occur when an attempt is made to navigate away from a cell.

```
    private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewLinkCell cell in 
            ((DataGridView) sender).SelectedCells.OfType<DataGridViewLinkCell>())
        {
            if (cell.Selected)
            {
                cell.LinkColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
            }
        }

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewLinkCell cell in
            ((DataGridView) sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells.OfType<DataGridViewLinkCell>())
        {
            cell.LinkColor = cell.LinkVisited ? Color.Purple : Color.Blue;
        }
    }
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Please see my "Edit" at the end for further clarification.

Comment: thank you for trying to help. This still does not work. When a row (or cell in the fist column) is selected it still shows the same result as in figure 1 of my original post above. I'm amazed - Microsoft should have noticed by now this odd default coloring format of the link column on a selection of row (or a cell on that column).

Comment: You need to do both `dataGridView1_SelectionChanged` as in your post and `dataGridView1_CellLeave`. I provided the whole example.

Comment: it still does not work. You may have taken your screenshot when you had put a `breakpoint` in one of the two events. I noticed the same when I put a `breakpoint` and when the code reaches the `breakpoint` I hit F5 then it works otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: I don't have breakpoints. It works for me outside debugger, too. I can prove it or, better, you can investigate what difference does breakpoint make. It's your project. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I've experienced the same issue and I got it working using the `CellFormatting` event. Below you'll find a generic solution for this:

```
void grd_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    SetGridLinkColor(sender as DataGridView, e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex, Color.White);
}

public static void SetGridLinkColor(DataGridView grd, int rowIndex, int columnIndex, Color selectedColor)
{
  if (grd == null || !(grd.Columns[columnIndex] is DataGridViewLinkColumn))
    return;

  if (grd.Rows[rowIndex].Selected)
  {
    ((DataGridViewLinkCell)grd.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex]).LinkColor = selectedColor;
    ((DataGridViewLinkColumn)grd.Columns[columnIndex]).VisitedLinkColor = selectedColor;
  }
  else
  {
    Color color = ((DataGridViewLinkColumn)grd.Columns[columnIndex]).LinkColor;
    ((DataGridViewLinkCell)grd.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex]).LinkColor = color;
    ((DataGridViewLinkColumn)grd.Columns[columnIndex]).VisitedLinkColor = color;
  }
}
```