# DataGridviewLinkCell - Change the fore color of highlighted cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview with 1 column being of type DataGridviewLinkColumn, the link text is in blue color and when the focus is on a cell the background color of the cell is also in blue color which makes it hard to read the cell value.

using the below link ,I tried changing the text background color to white when the focus is on that cell and it works fine as expected.

[SelectionForeColor not working for link cells in DataGridViewLinkColumn of DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596777/selectionforecolor-not-working-for-link-cells-in-datagridviewlinkcolumn-of-datag)

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewLinkCell cell in 
        ((DataGridView) sender).SelectedCells.OfType<DataGridViewLinkCell>())
    {
        if (cell.Selected)
        {
            cell.LinkColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
        }
    }

}

private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewLinkCell cell in
        ((DataGridView) sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells.OfType<DataGridViewLinkCell>())
    {
        cell.LinkColor = cell.LinkVisited ? Color.Purple : Color.Blue;
    }
}
```

However when the data is loaded into the Datagridview by default there is focus on the 1st cell i.e Cell[0] in Row[0] , in this case the fore color does not change to white, once i start changing the cell focus it works.

In the initial state how can i set the DataGridviewLinkColumn text color to white when the focus is by default ?

Also when i change the focus to any other control outside of datagridview the highlighted cell link text color change back to blue.

Comment: When you say initial state do you mean when the program is launched/started?

Comment: if it's on initial program launch then call your change colour code after the InitializeComponent() function.

Comment: not when the application is launched, but when the user selects an item from the dropdown list outside of datagridview and clicks on submit button the datagridview is diaplayed.... this is when the data is loaded in to the datagridview and the grid is displayed to the user.

Comment: how is the data loaded, do you do it in your own code, or is the datagrid linked to a data source?

Comment: put the colour change code in the submit button click event, after the data is loaded and the grid is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the `DataGridViewLinkCell` class and then set the `LinkColor` if the `cellState` is currently selected.

E.g:

```
public class DataGridViewLinkCell2 : DataGridViewLinkCell {

    private static PropertyInfo piVisitedLinkColorInternal = null;
    private static PropertyInfo piLinkColorInternal = null;

    static DataGridViewLinkCell2() {
        // use reflection, otherwise setting the properties directly calls InvalidateCell(...)
        // or InvalidateColumn(...) which results in an infinite loop of screen refreshing
        Type ty = typeof(DataGridViewLinkCell);
        piVisitedLinkColorInternal = ty.GetProperty("VisitedLinkColorInternal", BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        piLinkColorInternal = ty.GetProperty("LinkColorInternal", BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    }

    protected override void Paint(Graphics g, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts) {
        Color origLinkColor = this.LinkColor;
        Color origVisitedLinkColor = this.VisitedLinkColor;
        if (cellState == (cellState | DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)) {
            Color c = cellStyle.SelectionForeColor;
            piLinkColorInternal.SetValue(this, c);
            piVisitedLinkColorInternal.SetValue(this, c);
        }

        base.Paint(g, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
        // put back original, otherwise cells that were previously selected keep the new color
        piLinkColorInternal.SetValue(this, origLinkColor);
        piVisitedLinkColorInternal.SetValue(this, origVisitedLinkColor);
    }
}


        var colLink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn { Name = "Blah", DataPropertyName = "Blah" };
        colLink.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewLinkCell2();

        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgv.Columns.Add(colLink);
```